# Is a primitive function returned from other function different from primitive function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why the codes below behave that?

```
function hasOwnProperty() {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
}
hasOwnProperty()() //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty() // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === hasOwnProperty() // true
```

Comment: You have extra brackets when calling the method hasOwnProperty()()

Comment: What of the shown behavior is not clear to you. Where did you expect another result and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty()()` runs the function `hasOwnProperty` stored in `Object.prototype`, but it runns it in the context of `undefined`, so you get the error `cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

It is the same as if you would do this with the `push` function of an array, the `push` in this case is not called for `arr` anymore but without any context:

```js
var array = []
var push = array.push

console.log(push === array.push) // true
console.log(push === Array.prototype.push) // true

array.push(1) //works as expected
push(2) // fails because push is called without an object
```

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` runns the `hasOwnProperty` in the context of the object referenced by `Object.prototype`, so this does not return an error.

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === hasOwnProperty()` returns `true` because both reference the same function.

The important part is how you call that `hasOwnProperty` function. The `hasOwnProperty` will internally use `this` to check if the property name passed to `hasOwnProperty` exist on `this`.

So you need to call `hasOwnProperty` on an object otherwise `this` would be `undefined`.

What context a function has if it is not called on an object depends on the environment it is running on and if it is in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or not.

If the function is not in strict mode it will be `window` in a browser:

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this === window)
}

test();
```

But most modern code runs in strict mode and then `this` will be `undefined`:

```js
'use strict'
 
function test() {
 
  console.log(this)
}

test();
```

For modern code functions will most likely be always in strict mode.

Comment: Why is the context `undefined`, not `window`?

Comment: @ApriloySun I updated the answer. Most modern code utilizes strict mode, if it does not right now it most likely will in future.

Comment: Em. Is the function `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` in strict mode by default? I don't know whether it is a primitive performance or not.

Comment: @ApriloySun yes it is by default in strict mode. I'm almost certain (without knowing for sure)  that all API functions a modern browser provide run in strict mode. The same is for many modern libraries. And as I said if they are not in strict mode right now you should assume that they will switch to strict mode in future. There is actually no argument to not using strict mode except if you need to deal with legacy code, that was coded sloppy and would break in strict mode.